# Reuse parser within another parser with Scala parser combinators

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

I have a parser for arithmetic expressions:

```
object FormulaParser extends JavaTokenParsers {
  def apply(input: String) = parseAll(formula, input)
  // ...

  val formula: Parser[Formula] = 
    comparison | comparable | concatenable | term | factor
}
```

I need to parse a different language that can contain formulas. Let's say I need to parse something like `X < formula`. Unfortunately I cannot reuse `FormulaParser.formula` in my new parser:

```
object ConditionParser extends JavaTokenParsers {
  def apply(input: String) = parseAll(condition, input)
  // ...

  val condition: Parser[Condition] = 
    "X" ~ ("<=" | "<") ~ FormulaParser.formula ^^ { ... }  // doesn't work
}
```

because the parser on the left-hand side of `~` is an instance of `ConditionParser.Parser`, so its `~` method expects something with that same type, not something of type `FormulaParser.Parser`.

The whole point of using parser combinators is, well, combining parsers! It seems silly to me that my first attempt didn't work, although I understand why it happens (we are reusing base parsers by extending a base trait).

Is there a simple way to combine parsers defined in different types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to reuse parsers, you need to use inheritance. So if you make `FormulaParsers` a class or a trait, ConditionParser can inherit from it and reuse its parsers.

This is also how you're already reusing the parsers defined in `JavaTokenParsers`.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up creating a `BaseParsers` trait and having both parsers inherit from it.